# Using Lambda function in boost::unordered_set of strings - case insensitive

Tags: c++, lambda, string-comparison, case-insensitive, unordered-set

Objective : Need to have boost::unordered_set of strings - case insensitive.
But this set is a member variable of a class.

If it is not a member variable, I can create this set as follows. It works for me.

```
auto hash= [](const std::string& s) -> size_t
{
    size_t seed = 0;
    //Logic
    return seed;
};

auto equal= [](const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2)
{ 
    return boost::algorithm::iequals(s1, s2, std::locale());
};

typedef boost::unordered_set<std::string, decltype(hash), decltype(equal) > StringSet;
```

As my boost::unordered_set is a class member, I can't define it as above.

How I create this class member with lambda functions instead of functors.

Comment: what did you try already? pls give a [mcve].

Comment: Probably a typo but... extra `;` before `StringSet`?

Comment: Second and third type parameters of `boost::unordered_set` need to be `DefaultConstructible` but default constructor of lambda is deleted function, so it can be created only by calling `StringSet ss(N,hash,equal)` or in the same way in initializer list of constructor of a class if StringSet object is class member.

Comment: all my misunderstanding are caused because you are not giving a complete example. Show some context. How are you creating `StringSet` objects? How do you (want) to create the class member? Give us something to work with, or we cannot help you.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

https://wandbox.org/permlink/qz8mbCY57BNPbZEU

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/unordered_set.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/algorithm.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/predicate.hpp>

template <typename H, typename E>
struct my_class_with_member_set {
    boost::unordered_set<std::string, H, E > _set;
    my_class_with_member_set(std::size_t s, H h, E e):_set(s,std::move(h),std::move(e)){}
};

int main(){
    auto hash= [](const std::string& s) -> size_t
    {
        size_t seed = 0;
        //Logic
        return seed;
    };

    auto equal= [](const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2)
    { 
        return boost::algorithm::iequals(s1, s2, std::locale());
    };

    my_class_with_member_set my_class(42,hash,equal);
    my_class._set.insert("foo");
    my_class._set.insert("bar");


    return my_class._set.size();
}
```

-- update --

or:

https://wandbox.org/permlink/UWVV2puGXWXWLqvC

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/unordered_set.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/algorithm.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/predicate.hpp>

class my_class_with_member_set {
    constexpr static auto hash= [](const std::string& s) -> size_t
    {
        size_t seed = 0;
        //Logic
        return seed;
    };

    constexpr static auto equal= [](const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2)
    { 
        return boost::algorithm::iequals(s1, s2, std::locale());
    };

public:
    boost::unordered_set<std::string, decltype(hash), decltype(equal) > _set;
    my_class_with_member_set(std::size_t s):_set(s,hash,equal){}
};

int main(){
    my_class_with_member_set my_class(42);
    my_class._set.insert("foo");
    my_class._set.insert("bar");


    return my_class._set.size();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Having class member types depend on lambdas is painful and I would not recommend it. In this case it's probably easiest to go the "old" route of using a functor class instead of a lambda (I know you want to avoid it, but any other solution is significantly more complicated):

```
struct MyHasher
{
    size_t operator()(std::string& s) const
    {
        size_t seed = 0;
        //Logic
        return seed;
    }
}
struct MyEqual
{
    size_t operator()(const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2) const
    {
        return boost::algorithm::iequals(s1, s2, std::locale());
    }
}

class MyClassWithSet
{
    boost::unordered_set<std::string, MyHasher, MyEqual> _set;
}
```

You can do the thing suggested in the other answer and template your class containing the set on the hasher and equal comparer types, then use a template function to create instances of the class (to get the template deduction), but that is very intrusive and makes the class containing the set hard to use anywhere - in particular, you will have the same problem *again* if that class is needed as a member somewhere.

Is there any particular reason why you want to avoid functor classes?